# How do I create a second Central Admin in a different language on the same server?

Tags: central-administration, installation

I'm working in Sweden, and have Swedish customers. I'm native in Swedish and my customers have installed their Central Administration in Swedish too. The problem is that I'm not familiar with the translated terms since they look like being translated using a machine.

So I want to create a second Central Admin in English on another URL, but I don't know how? **How do I create a second Central Admin in a different language on the same server?**

Comment: You can switch language like any other sharepoint site if you have the language pack installed, don't think youll need to "create" a second CA tbh

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question entirely, but if you install a language pack, Central Administration should be available in that language too.

For example, If your customer installed the Swedish based version of SharePoint then install the English language pack and you'll be able to run Central Administration in English if you want too. You don't have to create a second central administration site.

If you enable multiple languages for your Central Administration, you can switch between them:

[image]

If you installed language packs, you can choose to enable multiple languages (MUI) via site settings:

[image]

Additional Central Administration sites can be deployed via Services on Server or via PowerShell, but it don't think you can run them on the same server.

Comment: +1 Thanks, this looks easier than creating a hole new site.

Comment: When you apply language packs to an existing install, be sure to follow the right installation steps, language packs with service pack integrated & reapply cumulative updates if needed

Comment: In addition to what Thomas said, Language packs does translate most but not all of central administration content when you change language (its actually installed using) into a different language.

Comment: +1 You cannot install multiple Central Administration Web sites on the same server.

You can install Central Administration Web site on multiple servers in the SharePoint farm. A good reason to do this is for high availability, incase the primary Central Administration Web site goes down. But not for the reason of handling multiple languages.